# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy' in opencv2

Tags: python, opencv, tuples, video-capture

I've been using OpenCV-python recently in order to do some Augmented Reality and I've encountered this error recently:

```
    imgAug = imgWebcam.copy()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

when launching the following code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
imgTarget = cv2.imread('TargetImage.jpg')
myVid = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
 
detection = False
frameCounter = 0
 
success, imgVideo = myVid.read()

imgWebcam = cap.read()
imgAug = imgWebcam.copy()
```

Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cap.read()` returning tuple, so you must unpack it like with `myVid.read()`.

```
success, imgVideo = myVid.read()

ret, imgWebcam = cap.read() # unpacking
imgAug = imgWebcam.copy()
```